# RegisterExternalEvaluator with command line options

Tags: external-calls, version-12

I'm trying to register NodeJS as an external evaluator in Mathematica 12.0.
This works fine generally speaking. (i.e. following https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureNodeJSForExternalEvaluate.html)

What I'm trying to do extra is to run node with a command line option.

i.e. if I would run `node -r esm` from the terminal, I would like to do something like,

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator["NodeJS", "/usr/bin/node -r esm"]
```

but this doesn't work, returning the error:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator::location: The executable /usr/bin/node -r esm isn't usable for ExternalEvaluate.
```

Any ideas?